# Does the SQL/JSON Path specification allow accessing the property of a filter expression's result

Tags: postgresql, oracle, json-path

I noticed a difference in the evaluation of a SQL/JSON path expression between Oracle and Postgres and I wonder which one is correct.

Consider the following JSON structure:

```
{
  "key1": {"id":1000, "price": 42},
  "key2": {"id":2000, "price": 3.14},
  "key3": {"id":3000, "price": 2.7}
}
```

To get the price of the product with ID = 1000, Postgres allows me to use the following JSON path expression:

```
jsonb_path_query(doc, '$.* ? (@.id == 1000).price')
```

However, when using Oracle's `json_value()` (or `json_query()` - doesn't matter)

```
json_value(doc, '$.* ? (@.id == 1000).price')
```

I get the following error (using Oracle 18c):

> ```
>  ORA-40597: JSON path expression syntax error ('$.* ? (@.id == 1000).price')
>  JZN-00209: Unexpected characters after end of path
>  at position 21
> ```

There is workaround in Oracle 18c:

```
json_value(json_query(doc, '$.* ? (@.id == 1000)'), '$.price')
```

So my question is:

Does the SQL standard allow the property access as done in Postgres' implementation?
Or is this simply not specified in the standard and marked as "implementation dependent"?

<sup>(Given Postgres' track record with sticking to the standard as much as possible, I suspect Postgres is correct and Oracle is not implementing the full standard)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know about the standard, but it works just fine in 19c.

Script:

```
[oracle@o73 ~]$ cat x.sql
with d as (select
'{
  "key1": {"id":1000, "price": 42},
  "key2": {"id":2000, "price": 3.14},
  "key3": {"id":3000, "price": 2.7}
}' as c1
from dual
)
select json_value(c1, '$.* ? (@.id == 1000).price') x
from d;

with d as (select
'{
  "key1": {"id":1000, "price": 42},
  "key2": {"id":2000, "price": 3.14},
  "key3": {"id":3000, "price": 2.7}
}' as c1
from dual
)
select json_value(json_query(c1, '$.* ? (@.id == 1000)'), '$.price') x
from d;

exit
[oracle@o73 ~]$
```

18c (18.10):

```
[oracle@o73 ~]$ . oraenv
ORACLE_SID = [oracle] ? RYMIN18
The Oracle base has been set to /u01/app/oracle
[oracle@o73 ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba @x

SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Jun 5 10:50:17 2020
Version 18.10.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.10.0.0.0

with d as (select
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-40597: JSON path expression syntax error ('$.* ? (@.id == 1000).price')
JZN-00209: Unexpected characters after end of path
at position 21



X
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
42

Disconnected from Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.10.0.0.0
[oracle@o73 ~]$
```

19c (19.7):

```
[oracle@o73 ~]$ . oraenv
ORACLE_SID = [RYMIN18] ? RYMIN19
The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /u01/app/oracle
[oracle@o73 ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba @x

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Jun 5 10:50:31 2020
Version 19.7.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.7.0.0.0


X
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
42


X
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
42

Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.7.0.0.0
[oracle@o73 ~]$
```

Comment: You are right about 19c - I thought I tested it there, but apparently that server wasn't upgraded yet and was still running 18.7. So it seems it's just a matter of "not supported yet".